# Sum object values with the same key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am kinda new to javascript and today I encountered problem. Thing is, I have an array of amount of people visited every day by each hour (as you can see bellow). And I would like to find out most popular hour of day. My plan was to create a map where key is index of hour (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) and value is sum of all people who visited across all days on that hour. Problem is I'm not able to do that with my JS knowledge. Can someone give me a direction how to approach this problem? Thank you very much.

```
[
   {date: "25.05.2018",
     value: {
       1: 209
       2: 123
       3: 890
       .
       .
       24: 789
     }
    }, 
    {date: "26.05.2018",
     value: {
       1: 280
       2: 398
       3: 450
       .
       .
       24: 76
     }
    } 
 ]
```

My JAVA like solution:

```
const { data: { data: [{ values }] } } = insightsData;

  const timesMap = new Map();

  values.forEach(item => {
    Object.entries(item.value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const timeValue = timesMap.get(key);
      if (timeValue) {
        timesMap.set(key, timeValue + value);
      } else {
        timesMap.set(key, value);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: you could start with the wanted result, like the given value property and iterate the array with thjeir values and add the items with the same index.

Comment: Understand that this is complex for your knowledge level but Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or *"how to"* tutorial service either. Start small by first figuring out how to loop over the array and then loop over the `value` array in each and add those values together in another object. Then when you figure that out figure out how to get the highest and where it comes from

Comment: Take a look at the [map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Well, I can write that using Map and forEach, but thought you could show me something more functional with map and reduce maybe? But I understand, I should ask somwhere else :)

Comment: @Pogasta if you were to use those methods and show your attempts you will get more help rather than expecting others to do all the work for you. The objective here is for people to help you fix **your code**

Comment: you could add you attempt and then we have a look. do you have for any day 24 elements?

Comment: @Pogasta It would be helpful if you provide an expected output, as well as an attempt at your solution (even if it doesn't work or isn't ideal) so we can see how far along you are. I don't fully understand the problem - do you have multiple date objects, each with a `values` array? Do you want to sum across multiple arrays into a single summed `values` array?

Comment: **value** refers an array of length 24, right? And you want to get max value from this array after creating a map. Am I correct? I can help you in this. And the given object is your i/p or you have an array of objects as i/p where object is the object that you have mentioned in the problem?

Comment: OK guys, added my solution

Comment: As I understood, you have an array of objects (like the one mentioned in problem), eg. `arr = [{date: "26.05.2018",
 value: [
   125,
   100,
   200,
   .
   .
   .
 ]
} , {date: "27.05.2018",
 value: [
   165,
   400,
   300,
   .
   .
   .
 ]
} , ....]` and you want map like `{0:290, 1:500, 2:500, ...}`.Finally you want most popular day. Am I right?

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani exactly...only value is an object where key is hour and value is count, thought it was an array, my bad...gonna edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you have arrays with the same length.

`reduce` takes an array as accumulator `r` and uses a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) with a zero as value if an item does not exist in the accumulator.

```js
var counts = [{ date: "26.05.2018", value: [125, 100, 200] }, { date: "27.05.2018", value: [5, 6, 7] }, { date: "28.05.2018", value: [3, 4, 5] }],
    result = counts.reduce(
        (r, { value }) => value.map((v, i) => (r[i] || 0) + v),
        []
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

With objects as `value` properties.

```js
var counts = [{ date: "26.05.2018", value: { 0: 125, 1: 100, 2: 200 } }, { date: "27.05.2018", value: { 0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7 } }, { date: "28.05.2018", value: { 0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5 } }],
    result = counts.reduce(
        (r, { value }) => Object
            .entries(value)
            .reduce((s, [k, v]) => {
                s[k] = (s[k] || 0) + v;
                return s;
            }, r),
        {}
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great solution, but is there a way to do it like that, but when value is an object like this {0: 150, 1:250, 2:80} instead of an array? I can map through object entries, but dont know how to ensure the resulting array is in right order (so I can determine, which sum is for which hour)? @Nina Scholz

Answer (score -1):

You can do iteratre over the values and add them to sum, like this

```
const data =  {date: "26.05.2018",
 value: [
   125,
   100,
   200,
 ]
} 

let sum = 0;
Object.values(data.value).forEach(elem => sum = sum + elem)
console.log(sum)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wwzn4yt/

Comment: But that is not the objective to sum them all into one `sum`. This answer is simply sending OP down wrong track

Comment: oops, this happens if you hearthstone while reading stackoverflow ;.-)